# C++ unordered_map initialization what happens to the underlying

Tags: c++

Inconsistance happens!

This piece of code goes well

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> topKFrequent(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
        unordered_map<int, int> num_freq_map;
        for(const auto &ele : nums) {
            ++num_freq_map[ele];
        }
    }
};
```

but when I changed from `unordered_map<int, int> num_freq_map;` to `unordered_map<int, int> num_freq_map`**`()`**`;` , appending a pair of brackets.

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> topKFrequent(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
        unordered_map<int, int> num_freq_map();
        for(const auto &ele : nums) {
            ++num_freq_map[ele];
        }
    }
};
```

I got an error:
`Line 6: lvalue required as increment operand`

Why? What happend to my variable `num_freq_map` when initializing?

How should I learn this sort of things. Read the Standard Template Library source code, right?

Comment: Basically it thinks you are declaring a function. Don't use the `()` if there are no arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The

`unordered_map<int, int> num_freq_map();`

defines `num_freq_map` as a pointer to a function that does not take any parameters and returns `unordered_map<int, int>`. But don't worry, as

`unordered_map<int, int> num_freq_map;`

already calls the correct default constructor for you. If you want to make the call explicit to the reader, in C++11 you can use brace-initialization:

`unordered_map<int, int> num_freq_map{};`

Comment: No, not a pointer to a function. A function.

Answer (score 1):

```
unordered_map<int, int> num_freq_map();
```

is interpreted as following:

`num_freq_map` is a function without parameters which returns `unordered_map<int, int>` .

To learn this sort of things, read the C++ FAQ by Marshall Cline.

There is no such thing as "the STL source code". STL has many different implementations.  I also doubt that reading a STL source code is useful, unless you have some very specific problem.